# Show that a random variable uniformly distributed over the unit square is independent

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

> Let $X=(U,V)$ be a random variable which is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]^2$. I want to show that $U$ is independent of $V$.

Let $A,B\in B([0,1])$ where $B([0,1])$ denotes the Borel Sigma algebra.

We have,

$$\begin{aligned}P(U\in A, V\in B) &= P((U,V)\in A\times B) \\&=1_{[0,1]^2}(A\times B) \\ &=1_{[0,1]}(A) \cdot 1_{[0,1]}(B) \\ &=P(U\in A)P(V\in B) \end{aligned}$$

Is my solution correct? What could I have done better?

Comment: Not every set in $\mathcal{B}([0,1]^2)$ is of the form $A \times B$ for $A, B \in \mathcal{B}([0,1])$. So from here you  can use the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem to complete the proof.

Comment: @Enforce sorry I don't get what you mean by $\pi -\lambda$ theorem?

Comment: What is wrong with $P(U=u)=P(U=u|V=v)$? Or $\mathbb{E}[UV]=\mathbb{E}[U]\mathbb{E}[V]$? Are these not applicable to this specific question?

Comment: @C.Koca Yes that's what I would have done but maybe this is for course in measure theory.

Comment: @C.Koca but to write $\Bbb{E}(UV)=\Bbb{E}(U)\Bbb{E}(V)$ we need the indepencence of $U,V$ so that's a theorem we had

Comment: @Enforce This is also why I refrain myself from answering. The question looks simple enough but I can't understand the solution to be verified.

Comment: @Wave Doesn't this hold: $U, V$ independent $\Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{E}[UV]=\mathbb{E}[U]\mathbb{E}[V]\Longleftrightarrow \sigma_{UV}=0$? Do I not remember it correctly?

Comment: @C.Koca ah right its an iff statement I somehow forgot the other implication. Thanks!

Comment: No i'ts clear!!

Comment: @C.Koca But I still have one question. I mean $B([0,1]^2)$ is the sigma algebra generated by all the open sets in $[0,1]^2$ but the open sets in $[0,1]^2$ are generated by $A\times B$ where $A,B\in [0,1]$ open right? So why exaclty can I show this fact only for the generators?

Comment: @Wave I have no idea about measurement theory. This is why you see me in the comments, not in the answers :)

Comment: @C.Koca "Doesn't this hold: $U, V$ independent $\iff \mathbb E[UV] = \mathbb E[U] \mathbb E[V]$" -- no, this isn't true. Having $\mathbb E[UV] = \mathbb E[U] \mathbb E[V]$ is a strictly weaker condition than having independence.

Comment: @Enforce do you know why my last comment do not work?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Thanks! This helps me as well.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery But in our case it holds.

Comment: @Wave No it doesn't. I checked after Aaron corrected me. $\mathbb{E}[UV]=\mathbb{E}[U]\mathbb{E}[V]$ tells you that they are uncorrelated, but not necessarily independent. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85363/simple-examples-of-uncorrelated-but-not-independent-x-and-y

Comment: @Wave No, if your task is to show that the variables are independent, then showing that they're uncorrelated (meaning $\mathbb E[UV] = \mathbb E[U] \mathbb E[V]$) is on its own not strong enough to show this. It is true that they're uncorrelated, of course, because they're independent -- but I don't think you can use the uncorrelated property to show independence here. The catch is that independent $\implies$ uncorrelated, **not** the other way around.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I see thanks!

Comment: How do you define variables being _uniformly distributed_ on the square or on the segment?

Comment: Hi Wave: To check for independence, check if $f(x,y) = f(x) * f(y)$. If that is true, then you have independence.

Comment: The * above should have been $\times$ so as to not confuse multiplication with convolution. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the variables are real valued, it seems simpler to use the [cumulative distribution functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_real_valued_random_variables)

For $0\le u,v \le 1$ we have

$$F_{U,V}(u,v)=P(U\le u, V  \le v) = u \, v = F_{U}(u)F_{V}(v) $$

hence they are independent.